# Apache apx module development - why are directives applying globally?

Tags: apache, module, config

I have developed an apache module which works ok. The directives are read from vhosts and apply ok.

The issue I’m struggling to resolve is when I have multiple vhosts with the directives applied, it appears to set the directive to the last setting, regardless of the website visited.

`

```
<vhost *:*>
    Servername www.abc.xyz

    Myconfig yes

</vhost>

<vhost *:*>
    Servername www.123.xyz

    Myconfig no

</vhost>
```

```
module AP_MODULE_DECLARE_DATA   example_module =
{
    STANDARD20_MODULE_STUFF,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    example_directives,
    register_hooks   /* Our hook registering function */
};
```

```
static void register_hooks(apr_pool_t *pool)
{
    /* Create a hook in the request handler, so we get called when a request arrives */
    ap_hook_handler(example_handler, NULL, NULL, APR_HOOK_LAST);
}
```

```
static const command_rec        example_directives[] =
{
    AP_INIT_TAKE1("Myconfig", my_function, NULL, RSRC_CONF, "Enable the module"),
    { NULL }
};
```

Regardless of whether I go to abc.xyz or 123.xyx, Myconfig is always the last vhost setting - in this case ‘no’

Any guidance would be appreciated.

I would expect each value to be within scope of the virtualhost with the servername.

I've also tried to wrap the directives within a Location tag:

```
<vhost *:*>
    Servername www.abc.xyz

    <Location /random>
        Myconfig yes
    </Location>
</vhost>

<vhost *:*>
    Servername www.123.xyz

    <Location /random>
        Myconfig no
    </Location>

</vhost>
```

```
static const command_rec        example_directives[] =
{
    AP_INIT_TAKE1("Myconfig", my_function, NULL, ACCESS_CONF, "Enable the module"),
    { NULL }
};
```

... and again, it doesn't matter which url I use or even what location I go to, it always applies the last directive.